# C++ storing template structures

Tags: c++, class, templates, struct, storage

I have a base structure `FooBase`:

```
struct FooBase { };
```

Then I create a template structure `Foo` which is a child of `FooBase`:

```
template <typename typeName> struct Foo : public FooBase { typeName* foo };
```

In some class I create a vector of `FooBase` and add instances of `Foo` in it:

```
vector <FooBase> FooVector
...    
Foo <Bar> fooInstance;
fooInstance.foo = new Bar();
FooVector.push_back ( fooInstance );
```

Then I needed to access the stored data, but I'm getting predictable and obvious error about an absence of the member `foo` in `FooBase`

```
FooVector[0].foo
```

I can not write something like

```
Foo <Bar> fooInstance = FooVector[0]
```

since I don't know the template parameter.

How do I store instances of `Foo` in the vector so I can access them later. **Note, that I don't know the template parameter at the last step - when reading data from the vector.**

**P.S. NO BOOST ALLOWED!**

Comment: can you just refer to `Bar` by `typename`?  Do you need to do anything with `Bar` that is specific to it's type (my guess would be no).

Comment: What you're looking for is a technique called type erasure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens here, is that in your

```
FooVector.push_back ( fooInstance );
```

line, C++ silently invokes the copy constructor of `FooBase`, because you can only keep objects of that type in your vector. Since `Foo` inherits publicly from `FooBase` the method `FooBase::FooBase(FooBase const&)` *can* be called with an object of type `Foo`.

So, you're not really storing `Foo`s, but in fact `FooBase`s. To do what you want to do you need an `std::vector<FooBase*>` or `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<FooBase> >`.

However, the contents of your vector, will *still* lack a `foo` member, because the static type is still not `Foo`. To get around this, you have some options. You *could* `dynamic_cast` or `static_cast` your `FooBase*` into a `Foo*` and then access its `foo` member. But that could break, since the `FooBase*` pointers might actually hold another type than `Foo`.

Why don't you just use an `std::vector<Foo<Bar> >` instead?

Comment: `Why don't you just use an std::vector<Foo<Bar> > instead?` Because I do not know the template parameter! Bar is just an example.

Comment: @Kolyunya: Then how can you possibly expect `.foo` to give you the right type?

Comment: That was my question. How to store a vector of template structures with template parameter which I do not know.

Comment: @Kolyunya: This doesn't make sense to me. Why would you try to extract an object which you don't even know the type of? Perhaps you could clarify your question. As it stands, I don't get it -- and apparently no one else.

Comment: And why do I need to know it's type??? I just need to get an access to it's memeber `foo` which is a pointer... I'm not getting it...

Comment: @Kolyunya: To access a member of a type `X` you need to know the full type `X`. No way around it. If `X` happens to be a template `Y<Z>` then you have to know which `Z` goes with the `Y`. How should C++ know what `.foo` is supposed to mean?

Comment: @bitmask: Or you need to implement functionality in a base class, using virtual functions if needed. Then you can use a pointer to the base class to refer to the object whose full type you do not know.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Yes, but you still wouldn't be accessing anything in the derived class. So there is no way around knowing the full type of something if you want to access any members.

Comment: @bitmask: Virtual functions. (Also, accessing members of the base class that are modified by functions in the derived class called by code that does know the full type.)

Answer (score 1):

You are slicing here:

```
vector <FooBase> FooVector
...    
Foo <Bar> fooInstance;
fooInstance.foo = new Bar();
FooVector.push_back ( fooInstance );
```

You are pushing a `Foo<Bar>` into a vector of `FooBase` so you only get a `FooBase` object stored. This

```
FooVector[0]
```

returns a reference to a `FooBase` which knows nothing about `Foo<Bar>`. You could store `Foo<Bar>` directly:

```
vector<Foo<Bar>> FooVector;
```

or store pointers or smart pointers to `FooBase`, but then you will have to dynamic_cast the elements to `Foo<Bar>*` anyway, which isn't a very nice solution.

Comment: Yes, I know it. How can I store a vector of `Foo`? Does it change anything if I put a pointer-to-Foo in the vector of pointers-to-FooBase?

Comment: @Kolyunya: A vector of pointers is one way to avoid slicing. However, it makes the vector's copy constructor and copy assignment do the wrong thing. It's one of the ugliest C++ problems, IMO. (Other ugly solutions include ptr_vector, boost::any, and vectors of smart pointers.)

Comment: @Kolyunya I added some options to my answer.

Comment: `but then you will have to dynamic_cast the elements to Foo<Bar>* anyway, which isn't a very nice solution.` I can not cast, because I don't know the value of template parameter. `Bar` is just an example

Comment: @Kolyunya: Then what could you possibly do with the returned object?! If you don't know its type, how would you even know which functions it supports or which data members it has? It sounds like you need to push any functionality you need to invoke on an object whose full type you don't know into the base class.

Comment: @Kolyunya it sounds like you need a re-design.

Comment: "vectors of smart pointers" - `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` works pretty fine.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I seriously doubt it. OP needs to cast to a derived type they don't even know.

Comment: That's bad. Well, the re-design is actually the best solution to 90% of c++ questions.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: The problem with vectors of smart pointers is that the semantics of copy construction and copy assignment (of the vector) probably won't do what you want because the objects will wind up shared. (Of course, if that's what you want then that's perfect. And if you needed smart pointers to those objects anyway, then it's absolutely perfect.)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in previous answers, you are slicing Bar into FooBase objects.  Your vector has to store references to Foo objects rather than the object itself.

The easiest way to accomplish this is to use one of the smart_ptr types from the boost library.

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <vector>
typedef std::vector< boost::shared_ptr<FooBase> > FooVector;
...
FooVector v;
v.push_back( new Bar() );
```

If you store the pointer itself into the vector you'll have problems with memory management, using the boost shared_ptr type will handle allocation for you automatically.

Comment: (You can also, of course, use smart pointer types for any other library or write your own, since you don't want to use Boost. The point is the semantics you need, not the implementation.)

Comment: As David mentioned you don't have to use boost; however you SHOULD use some kind of smart pointer implementation for your vector references.  And you MUST use reference types in your vector to avoid the slicing problem.  Failure to use smart pointers places the burden on YOU to handle deallocation; which makes using some of the vector methods (i.e., erase) extremely dangerous.